# Get list of all categories within Publication using Core Service?

Tags: core-service

I would like to get a list of all categories within a Publication, so then I can get all the keywords within the category.  I have found some examples of getting keywords, but not any of getting all categories within 1 Publication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `CategoriesFilterData`:

```
client.GetList(pubId, new CategoriesFilterData());
```

Comment: I knew it was easy, thanks!  Link is here for code sample, http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-973CC313-C411-4737-8263-F04D4378331C